# Enabling realtime HTML validation in VS Code and Atom

Tags: visual-studio-code, atom-editor

I am having a hard time finding out how to do this in either.  I would have expected that it would be built-in, as it is in VS Studio; where if a tag isn't closed, a curly underscore appears as a warning.
Incidentally JS and CSS code seems to be natively validated in both Code and Atom.  So why not HTML?

PS: even Notepad++ complains when a tag isn't closed..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Visual Studio Code, you can use the [`HTMLHint`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkaufman.HTMLHint) extension, which integrates the [HTMLHint](https://github.com/yaniswang/HTMLHint) static analysis tool into VSCode.

Answer (score 2):

At least in Atom, nothing is validated by default. You need to install a linter for the language you want to validate (or linted, as it's commonly called).

A popular linter is the Atom package of the same name – [linter](https://atom.io/packages/linter). Once installed, you need additional providers for the syntax you want to lint. All available providers are listed on the [AtomLinter website](http://atomlinter.github.io/), including [HTML](http://atomlinter.github.io/#language-html), [CSS](http://atomlinter.github.io/#language-css) and [JavaScript](http://atomlinter.github.io/#language-js).

As for Visual Studio Code, you can install a variety of linters from their [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode/linters?sortBy=Downloads).

Comment: there was no variety at that time for VS, and now there in one, as mentioned in the "accepted answer"